# MongoDB pull first matching nested array item

Tags: mongodb

I have the following documents...

```json
{ "_id": 2, "name": "Jane Doe", "phones": [ { "type": "Mobile", "digits": [ { "val": 1 }, { "val": 2 } ] }, { "type": "Mobile", "digits": [ { "val": 3 }, { "val": 4 } ] }, { "type": "Land", "digits": [ { "val": 5 }, { "val": 6 } ] } ] }
{ "_id": 1, "name": "John Doe", "phones": [ { "type": "Land", "digits": [ { "val": 1 }, { "val": 2 } ] }, { "type": "Mobile", "digits": [ { "val": 0 }, { "val": 3 }, { "val": 4 } ] }, { "type": "Mobile", "digits": [ { "val": 3 }, { "val": 4 }, { "val": 9 } ] } ] }
```

...and the following MongoDB query...

```js
db.getCollection("persons").updateOne({"name": "John Doe"},
{
    "$pull":
    {
        "phones.$[condition1].digits":
        {
            "val: { $in: [ 3, 4 ] }
        }
    }
},
{
    arrayFilters:
    [
        { "condition1.type": "Mobile" }
    ]
})
```

My problem is that the query removes the last two elements of the array: "phones" of the second document (John Doe) and I want to remove only the first one (and not the last one that have a "9" among the digits). How I can delete only the first matching nested array item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- pipeline update
- reduce on phones, starting with `{"phones": [], "found": false}`
- if `[3,4]` subset of `digits.val`  and `not found` => ignore it
  else keep it (concat arrays to add the member)
- `$getField` to get the phones from the reduced `{"phones" : [...]}`

*`$pull` removes all elements that satisfy the condition, maybe there is a way with update operators and not pipeline update, but this works if you dont find more compact way

*alternative to reduce, could be 2 filters, one to keep the values that dont contain the [3,4] and one to keep those that contain, from those that contained, and then concat those arrays removing only one of those that contain the [3,4]

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=627ac73aad87e9cf3a92942e)

```js
update(
{"name": {"$eq": "John Doe"}},
[{"$set": 
   {"phones": 
     {"$getField": 
       {"field": "phones",
        "input": 
         {"$reduce": 
           {"input": "$phones",
            "initialValue": {"phones": [], "found": false},
            "in": 
             {"$cond": 
               [{"$and": 
                   [{"$not": ["$$value.found"]},
                     {"$setIsSubset": [[3, 4], "$$this.digits.val"]}]},
                 {"phones": "$$value.phones", "found": true},
                 {"phones": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value.phones", ["$$this"]]},
                  "found": "$$value.found"}]}}}}}}}])
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no real sense of motivation for this update, so I am unsure about the details of the logic.  I think I have taken the OP's words and partial demonstration literally and I've implemented an `update` pipeline to fix the stated problem.  Given the number of possibilities, this may not be what you are looking for.  My pipeline is very similar to the [@Takis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72192445/1409374), but the logic is slightly different and therefore the output is different.  I look forward to the OP's comments/questions to identify/clarify any discrepancies and/or ambiguities.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "name": "John Doe"
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "phones": {
        "$getField": {
          "field": "phones",
          "input": {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": "$phones",
              "initialValue": { "phones": [], "pullDone": false },
              "in": {
                "$cond": [
                  {
                    "$and": [
                      { "$eq": [ "$$this.type", "Mobile" ] },
                      { "$not": "$$value.pullDone" }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "pullDone": true,
                    "phones": {
                      "$concatArrays": [
                        "$$value.phones",
                        [
                          {
                            "$mergeObjects": [
                              "$$this",
                              {
                                "digits": {
                                  "$filter": {
                                    "input": "$$this.digits",
                                    "as": "digit",
                                    "cond": {
                                      "$not": [ { "$in": [ "$$digit.val", [ 3, 4 ] ] } ]
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "pullDone": "$$value.pullDone",
                    "phones": {
                      "$concatArrays": [ "$$value.phones", [ "$$this" ] ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ipWPp8HgVj6).